# Kibana to get elastic search data from multiple elastic search instances deployed in different datacenters in AWS

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

we are building dashboard for test results . Same test cases execute in multiple k8s clusters ( we organized as devus1, qaus1, produs1,prodeu1 ,prodanz1 ) . each environment we have seperate elastic search instance running . We want to get elastic search data from all those environments to build a kibana dashboard with test results . Can someone please suggest a solution ?